# Collisions with randomly scattered objects

Tags: experimental-physics

On a tennis court I often have 20 – 50 tennis balls randomly scattered in a portion of the court. When gathering the balls I will occasionally kick one into the scatter. I am surprized that rarely does the kicked ball pass through the scatter without a collision. The successful passage of a ball through the scatter is likely a function of court surface area utilized, diameter of tennis ball, ball randomness, and number of tennis balls. I suspect that this is complex process. What branch of physics might be used to give a probability that a single kicked ball will pass through without a collision?

Answer (score 0):

It should be straightforward. Paint imaginary parallel stripes on the court, separated by the width of a tennis ball. The center of your ball will roll down one of the stripes. Any randomly placed ball whose center is within one stripe on either side of the rolling ball will be hit.

From the size of the court, you can figure out how many stripes there are. It will be more complex if the stripes are at an angle. So figure it out for the easy case - your ball happens to roll parallel to the sides of the court.Call it $S$. The odds of any other randomly placed ball being hit in 1 trial are $p=2/S$.

If the ball rolls at an angle, the length of the path may differ. It might cut a corner of the court. It might roll all the way across. For large $S$, the probability will be close to proportional to the length of the path.

You have $N$ balls that each have the same probability of being hit. Rolling a ball through a field of $N$ balls is equivalent of $N$ trials with 1 ball. The number of hits, $n$, is given by a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). The probability, P, of $n$ hits in $N$ trials, where each trial has probability p of success, is

$$P_p\ (n|N) = \frac{N!}{n!(N-n)!}\ p^n\ (1-p)^{N-n}$$

If N is large, this becomes a [Poisson distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PoissonDistribution.html).

$$P_\nu\ (n|N) = \frac{\nu^n\ e^{-\nu}}{n!}$$

where $\nu$ is the expected number of successes.

For the parallel-to-the-sides case,
$$\nu = Np = 2N/S$$

Comment: Could you define S?

Comment: S is the number of stripes. Suppose your stripes run parallel to the long edge of a tennis court. A tennis court is 36 feet wide, and a tennis ball is 2.57 - 2.70 inches in diameter, so S is 160 - 168. If you turn it sideways and draw the lines parallel to the net, half a tennis court is 39 feet long. In this case S is 173 - 182. Your tennis balls are scattered randomly in a rectangle. You can expect more hits if you kick a ball the long way through them.

Comment: I have worked a few examples using the binomial distribution, and modelled the case of three stripes with one randomly placed ball. In the latter case with S = 3 your formulas sets p = 2/S surely p =1/3?  That is, the probability of a collision is the width of a single randomly placed ball divided by total width of 3S?

Comment: p = 2/3. Both balls have width. Try it with 2 stripes. p = 1. You cannot avoid a collision.